# comparing unsigned vs signed does not make a warning (using const)

Tags: c, gcc, constants

Simple: If I test a signed vs an unsigned variable in GCC, when compiling `-Wall` I will get a warning.

Using this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    /* const */ unsigned int i = 0;
    if (i != argc)
        return 1;
    return 0;
}
```

I get this warning:

```
<source>: In function 'int main(int, char**)':
<source>:6:8: warning: comparison of integer expressions of different signedness: 'unsigned int' and 'int' [-Wsign-compare]
    6 |  if (i != argc)
      |      ~~^~~~~~~
Compiler returned: 0
```

However, if I uncomment this `const` - the compiler is happy. I can reproduce this on almost every GCC version (see https://godbolt.org/z/b6eoc1). Is is this a bug in GCC?

Comment: Why would it be a bug? Fairly few circumstances are required to be diagnosed by the compiler, and yours is not one of them, either way.  On the other hand, compilers are free to emit any additional diagnostics they care to do.  Even unhelpful ones.  That (by default) the compiler warnings are more accurate with `const` is a feature, not a bug.

Comment: gcc is pretty bad at warning for mixing signedness in the same expression. You can use `-Wconversion` to get more such warnings, but this option comes with a lot of false positives, so it is annoying for that reason.

Comment: @JohnBollinger: Re “Why would it be a bug? Fairly few circumstances are required to be diagnosed by the compiler…”: Because the definition of a bug is a failure to conform to specification, and the C standard is not the specification of GCC. It is part of the specification, incorporated by reference, but GCC has its own documentation about what it should and should not do, including additional warnings. Failing to issue a warning that its documentation states it will issue would be a bug.

Comment: Your Godbolt link is for GCC. The behavior is different in GCC’s C and C++ modes.

Comment: @EricPostpischil, I accept your definition of "bug" as a reasonable one, but not as the only plausible one, nor as one implied by the question.  If that is indeed what the OP had in mind when they posed the question then the a response along the lines you give, paired with a clarifying update to the question, would be a reasonable response for them to make.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd say it's a compiler bug in the `-Wsign-compare` option.

Test by compiling your example with `-Wall -Wextra -O3`. With `-O3` added, the warning suddenly goes away in the `const` case. Even though the generated machine code with or without `const` is identical. This doesn't make any sense.

Naturally, neither `const` nor the generated machine code has any effect on the signedness of the C operands, so the warning shouldn't come inconsistently depending on type qualifiers or optimizer settings.

Comment: I tend to agree. Clang does not have this "bug". Seems like a (very minor) compiler bug to me.

Answer (score 5):

I think that what you are missing is compiler optimization. Without const, that variable is a variable, meaning that it can change. Since it is an unsigned int, it means that indeed it can be larger than an integer.

```
const unsigned int i = 2147483648;
```

You will get your error back if you assign a value greater than the largest value of int to that unsigned int.

However if it is const, the compiler knows its value, it knows, that it will not change, and there will be no problem with the comparison.

If you take a look at the assembly, you will see that without const, it actually takes the value of the variable to compare:

```
movl    $0, -4(%rbp)
movl    -20(%rbp), %eax
cmpl    %eax, -4(%rbp)
```

Now, if it is const, it will not bother with the variable at all, it just takes the value:

```
movl    $0, -4(%rbp)
cmpl    $0, -20(%rbp)
```

Comment: It is not related to the question. There is no working in both cases https://godbolt.org/z/nTdhnY

Comment: I think that it is related, the question is basically why the compiler is happy with it if it is const and ehy it is not happy with it if it is not a const. My reply answeres that question.

Comment: If it is not const, the compiler gives you a warning that that comparison might lead to undesired consequences, if it is const, and the range of the value if fine, then there is no possibility for that error, so there is no warning.

Comment: gcc and ubuntu versions: gcc (Ubuntu 9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04) 9.3.0, I could copy the same warning here, but that would not make much sense. Try it.

Comment: Oh yeah, I am using my laptop, not an online tool.

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/o6Gcce still nothing. Your version was compiled with `-Wsign-compare` enabled by default. But it does not have anything in common with const. You probably are not aware that you can build gcc yourself and have different options enabled than stated in the documentation

Comment: You might be right, but it is then quite a coincidence that it has nothing to do with constness, yet the warning disappears if it is a const. Kind of strange.

Comment: Another way to get the warning is to compare with an `extern const unsigned int foo;` with no definition of `foo` in scope, so that the compiler doesn't know the value of `foo`.

Comment: `const` isn't really that important for the compiler to determine if a variable is changed. In this case all updates of the variable happen from the same scope, in the same translation unit. The compiler can easily deduct that the variable isn't modified and optimize accordingly. And optimization in turn should have no relevance for the warning if the compiler was working correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Simple use `-Wall -Wextra` and you will get your warning back.

I would advise using `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic` compiler options

https://godbolt.org/z/TvqeKn

**EDIT**

As clarification to the very unfriendly and unkind OP comment. -Wextra enables the following warnings **including** the one which OP wants

[image]

```
warning: comparison of integer expressions of different signedness:
 'unsigned int' and 'int' [-Wsign-compare]
    9 |     if (i != argc)
```

Comment: That does not really answer the question. Even in `-Wall` this should have been cought. What am I missing?

Comment: @elcuco why do you think it should be with the -Wall? Did you write that gcc part which enables set of warnings with the command line option? This warning is enabled by `-Wextra` and it does answer the question.

Comment: I’d go even further: I recommend using `-pedantic-errors` instead of `-pedantic` at the very least. And for most build I also add `-Werror`.

Comment: @KonradRudolph in production build yes, but during the development, it IMO goes too far

Comment: You should use `-pedantic-errors` if you need C compliance. If you are developing something with gcc extensions (ie Linux non-standard crap), then you shouldn't use that option.

Comment: @Lundin I meant : when I write the code I prefer compilation to go even if there are some irrelevant warnings, which I will sort out later. When I have the production build all warnings are treated as errors.

Comment: @Lundin Yeah, I thought that part was obvious, since it wouldn’t work. :-) That said, I strongly recommend agains the use of extensions where avoidable, since it makes code non-portable, usually for no good reason.

Comment: @0___________ I disagree with that, and both common sense and (more importantly!) decades’ worth of good SE evidence backs me up: the earlier errors are fixed during development, the faster/cheaper those fixes are. Don’t wait until deployment to catch such errors! Catch and fix them as early as possible; i.e. during regular development builds.

Comment: @KonradRudolph `makes code non-portable` sometimes portability is the least important factor (for example uC development)

Comment: @0___________ But why hobble yourself unnecessarily? The vast, *vast* majority of code can be written with portability in mind. Even uC code: most of the logic won’t necessarily be platform-dependent, and if it’s written portably it can be used elsewhere in the future. That’s a *massive* boon, often (but admittedly not always) at low (or zero) cost. By contrast, prematurely locking yourself into a platform has almost no benefits. Even seasoned engineers make fallacious cost–benefit analyses here. Of course there are situations where this is unavoidable, I’m not talking about those.

Comment: ... and yet the `const` changes the error/warning issued. That is my original question.

Answer (score 0):

The question is tagged C but links to a C++ Godbolt example. Here is a table showing when the warning is issued:<sup>1</sup>

|  | C non-const | C const | C++ non-const | C++ const |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Default warnings | No | No | No | No |
| `-Wall` | No | No | Yes | No |
| `-Wall -Wextra` | Yes | Yes | Yes | No |

So, in C, GCC provides the warning in `-Wextra` regardless of `const` qualification.

In C++, GCC provides the warning in `-Wall` but treats `const` qualified objects as known values for which the warning may be suppressed.

The [GCC documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-10.2.0/gcc/Warning-Options.html#Warning-Options) says, for `-Wsign-compare`:

> Warn when a comparison between signed and unsigned values could produce an incorrect result when the signed value is converted to unsigned. In C++, this warning is also enabled by `-Wall`. In C, it is also enabled by `-Wextra`.

Note that it does not say it warns when there is a comparison between signed and unsigned values but rather when such a comparison could produce an incorrect result. Therefore, not providing a warning when the definition of the object is such that the comparison cannot produce an incorrect result is not a bug.

The word “could” leaves latitude for what the compiler “knows” about the object. Failing to determine the C `const` case cannot produce an incorrect result could be described as a bug although it may be better described as a shortcoming.

### Footnote

<sup>1</sup> “Const” in the table is specifically use of an object that is const-qualified and whose value is immediately available to the compiler via a visible definition. I did not test cases where, for example, an identifier is declared for a const-qualified object but its definition is in another translation unit.

Comment: Although illustrative, a table of GCC behavior under various circumstances is not by itself responsive to the question ("Is is [sic] this a bug in GCC?"). Inasmuch as you have asserted that the term "bug" should be interpreted as deviation from specifications, I suppose you have forgotten to pair that table with the relevant specifications.

Comment: @JohnBollinger: Sure it is, because, for the C that the question was tagged with, the compiler provides the requested behavior regardless of `const`. The question of whether there was a bug providing the warning when `const` was present vanishes; it was OP’s error to use C++ instead of C. If they want to ask about C++, that is another matter.

Comment: `const` qualified objects don't always have known values. (There needs to be a _definition_ of the object in scope for the value to be known.) If the value isn't known, the warning isn't suppressed, which is reasonable enough.

Comment: @IanAbbott: Footnote added.

Comment: And then `-Wall -Wextra -O3` https://godbolt.org/z/rvGqar. Suddenly no warning. It's very hard to call this inconsistent behavior anything but a compiler bug.

Comment: @Lundin: Your link shows a C++ compilation for which `-Wall -Wextra` produces no warning, as shown in the table in this answer, and add `-O3` does not change anything.  For C, adding `-O3` does result in the warning vanishing. This is attributable to the compiler doing further analysis as part of optimization and thus deducing that the comparison cannot produce an “incorrect” result. As noted in the last paragraph of the answer, the phrasing in the documentation leaves latitude for this.

Comment: I just grabbed the OP's godbolt for this comment, which I now realize is using C++. But when I played around with this yesterday I used gcc for C. Anyway, the compiler can't assume a thing about `argc`, even though C has a rule for argc specifically saying it should be non-negative. Swapping it for an `extern int a; .. if(i != a)` doesn't improve the situation. https://godbolt.org/z/zbefsj. Even though the compiler obviously can't do a thing about the extern, the warning goes away with -O3 even though `a` is explicitly loaded with an unknown value from RAM `mov     edx, DWORD PTR a[rip]`.

Comment: @Lundin: Re “… the compiler can't assume a thing about argc, even though C has a rule”: The opposite is true; a compiler may take statements of the C standard as axioms. However, that is irrelevant, per the following. Re “`extern int a; .. if(i != a)`”: This is not a bug because any `int` value of `a` results in the desired result: Even after conversion to `unsigned`, `i != a` is true only if `a` is not zero. Conversion of `a` to `unsigned` produces zero if and only if `a` is zero, so the comparison can never provide a result different from the mathematical `i` ≠ `a`.

Comment: @EricPostpischil I am reproducing this on pure C code (a compiler based on gcc8.2 for esp32). The Windows and Linux native cross-compilers behave differently. It does seem like a port/compiler bug to me. Thanks for the details though.